# Rename [gorouter] to [cloud-foundry-gorouter]

Tags: discussion

[gorouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorouter) is supposed to be used for the Cloud Foundry gorouter component. However, due to the similar naming to the popular flutter routing package `go_router`, it often ends up on those questions (which have their own tag [flutter-go-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-go-router)). I have only seen very few questions (in fact, co-tagged with [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) are [exactly two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorouter+go) and co-tagged with [cloud-foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-foundry) are [exactly five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorouter+cloud-foundry)) of the 113 questions with the gorouter tag.

I think clarifying the gorouter tag so it's not confused with flutter-go-router and retagging the existing gorouter tags to flutter-go-router to clean that up?

Let me know what you think!